# How to do I add date and time to name of folder that is created with python shutil?

Tags: python, datetime, shutil

I'm trying to write a python script that will automatically copy files in my local drive and to my network drive.  I want to add a the time and date to the name of the destination folder. This is my code:

```py
import shutil
import os
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now().strftime("%m_%d_%Y-%I:%M:%S")
src = 'C:/test_folder'
dst = 'Z:/Backup Files/backup_{}'.format(date)
```

When I do this I receive the following output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 shutil.copytree(src=src,dst=dst)

File C:\pyver\py3.10.5\lib\shutil.py:558, in copytree(src, dst, symlinks, ignore, copy_function, ignore_dangling_symlinks, dirs_exist_ok)
    556 with os.scandir(src) as itr:
    557     entries = list(itr)
--> 558 return _copytree(entries=entries, src=src, dst=dst, symlinks=symlinks,
    559                  ignore=ignore, copy_function=copy_function,
    560                  ignore_dangling_symlinks=ignore_dangling_symlinks,
    561                  dirs_exist_ok=dirs_exist_ok)

File C:\pyver\py3.10.5\lib\shutil.py:457, in _copytree(entries, src, dst, symlinks, ignore, copy_function, ignore_dangling_symlinks, dirs_exist_ok)
    454 else:
    455     ignored_names = set()
--> 457 os.makedirs(dst, exist_ok=dirs_exist_ok)
    458 errors = []
    459 use_srcentry = copy_function is copy2 or copy_function is copy

File C:\pyver\py3.10.5\lib\os.py:225, in makedirs(name, mode, exist_ok)
    223         return
    224 try:
--> 225     mkdir(name, mode)
    226 except OSError:
    227     # Cannot rely on checking for EEXIST, since the operating system
    228     # could give priority to other errors like EACCES or EROFS
    229     if not exist_ok or not path.isdir(name):

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Z:/Backup Files/backup_07_13_2022-12:27:22'
```

Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the Z drive mounted?

Comment: Consider using forward slashes instead of backslashes, and do not use colons (`:`) in the filename

Comment: @GrantMoore Yes. It's a MyCloud Home drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@FObersteiner was correct.  The reason why it wasn't working was due to that fact that windows 10 does not allow colons (`:`) to be used as a character for filenames.  I should have seen this myself.  Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

It is correct as [fobersteiner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10197418/fobersteiner) said.
As per windows: "A filename cannot contain any of the following characters: \ / : * ? " < > |"

You can also add date and time to filename in python like this:

```
old_file_name = "image1"
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%I_%M_%S_%p")
updated_filename = f'{old_file_name}_{date}'
print(updated_filename)
```

Output:

```
image1_2022_07_18-09_47_15_PM
```

so for you it becomes like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%I_%M_%S_%p")
src = 'C:/test_folder'
dst = f'Z:/Backup Files/backup_{date}'
print(dst)
```

Output:

```
Z:/Backup Files/backup_2022_07_18-10_08_11_PM
```

for more detail on %Y, %m, %d, %I, %M, %S, %p visit [strftime-and-strptime-format-codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)